# Merge records that have at least one non-null element in a specific column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data looks like as following:

```
id      ProteinID   Gene_Name   Class
10008   P08648      ITGA5       extracellular
10009   P08648      ITGA5       extracellular
10011   P08473      MME 10      NULL
10011   P08473      MME 10      extracellular
10013   P12111      COL6A3      NULL
10016   P09619      PDGFRB      NULL
10016   P09619      PDGFRB      intracellular
```

I would like to merge records that have both NULL and a NON-NULL value in the 
[Class] column but at the same time to not affect rows that have only a NULL value (e.g. id 10013)

Following is the desired output:

```
id      ProteinID   Gene_Name   Class
10008   P08648      ITGA5       extracellular
10009   P08648      ITGA5       extracellular
10011   P08473      MME 10      extracellular
10013   P12111      COL6A3      NULL
10016   P09619      PDGFRB      intracellular
```

I have tried using the `COALESCE` function but it expunges all the rows with NULL in [Class].

I'm sure there is a simple way of doing that but I've been stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a Gaps and Island Problem. You say you've tried `COALESCE`, can you show us you're attempt(s) please?

Comment: Is there a situation where there might be multiple classes on an `id`?

Comment: And, if there are multiple classes, how to you know which is "first"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is your intent

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By ID,ProteinID,Gene_Name  order by Class Desc)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: yes, I was looking exactly for something like this, it does the work.

Comment: @gkoul Happy it helped.  It works with the small sample provided.  Just take a hard look at the "REAL" data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT id, ProteinID, Gene_Name, MAX(class) as class
FROM t
GROUP BY id, ProteinID, Gene_Name;
```

If you want *all* non-null values, I might go for:

```
select t.*
from t
where class is not null
union all
select t.*
from t
where class is null and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.class is not null);
```